# structure.gantt a task that must be at certain time for a certain duration vs automatically scheduled tasks

Tags: gantt-chart, jira-plugin

I want to plan this guy's tasks, he has many tasks with different duration. at some certain point in the future he should have a 4 weeks of a task that must happen there. when I level his tasks there is a few weeks gap before that "must be done task" because no other automatically task can fit there.

1. why structure doesn't work like MS project in that manner - start an automatic sched task and spread the duration to accommodate that manual one
2. if there is no such feature, how can I handle such situation, I don't want a gap, I don't want to manually set tasks and I must have this one task at that point of time

Thanks,
Isri

I tried automatically scheduling, was expecting no gaps (a task will start and be finished after that must be task)

Instead I got a gap cause no task was able to fit